# Locally constant and continuous function implies constant?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume I have $a,b \in \mathbb{R},\ a < b$ and a function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is locally constant over its domain, and we define locally constant at a point $c$ as $\forall x \in [a,b], \exists \delta > 0 \ \ \ |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| =0$ (i.e. $f(x) = f(c)$). We want to prove that $f$ is constant over $[a,b]$.

My initial thought was we could start at $a$ and then consider $k=a + \delta(a)$ and then $[a,k)$ is guaranteed constant, and then do something where $k$ begins the next interval through some form of induction showing it's constant over the entire domain, but this seems very hand-wavy and seems to break down in some cases I'm considering.

Can this be done using only principles from basic analysis/calculus rather than topology? From my limited understanding I would be able to use the connectedness property of $[0,1]$ to show this, but is there a way to prove without diving too much into topology either by invoking some theorem like MVT or using the definition directly? I didn't know if we could invoke MVT since we would need to show the stronger condition of differentiability.

Comment: Your definition of locally constant is missing a "there exists a $\delta > 0$" in the beginning

Comment: @peek-a-boo just fixed, thanks for catching that.

Comment: If $a = b$, the statement is trivial, so suppose $a< b$.

I believe your idea can indeed be made precise as follows: let $A = \left\{ x \in [a,b]: \, \, \text{$f$ is constant on $[a,x]$}\right\}$. Then, you have already shown that $a \in A$, and that there's a small (semi) open interval contained in $A$. This means $A$ is non-empty, and bounded above (by $b$). Hence, it has a supremum, $\xi := \sup A$.

So, by what you have already shown, we have that $a < \xi \leq b$. We now have to prove that $\xi \in A$ and that $\xi = b$ (I suggest using contradiction)

Comment: This is a type of argument which I learnt in my introductory calculus course (in Spivak's text), but really, its also the same type of argument which is used in topology to prove that an interval is connected.